# How can I make Thunderbird marks the indicators envelope blue?

Tags: indicator, thunderbird

Upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 now i don't have notifications on incoming email to Thunderbird on the indicator bar, neither when thunderbird is running nor when it's not.

None of the other similar questions answers have helped me. Still no blue envelope.

I DO get a notification when the email comes as a temporary OSD, ut the envelope in the indicators menu does not get blue and there is no line for received email under "Mail" althougth it is working for Google Mail.

Answer (score 1):

What finally worked:
Now I get a blue envelope on Thunderbird mail at the indicators menu. It also tells me in which folders do I have mail.

For that I had to install Thunderbirds Add-on "Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher integration 0.8" by mike_conley

BUT I am still NOT satisfied cause:

1) I need to keep the whole Thunderbird open, wasting precious memory while I am not looking at the mail. (I have 4GB that my Java apps eat up quite easily)

2) I have seen that there is a way that you get the unread count in the unity Thunderbird icon.  That would be best. How can I get that?

Do I need to keep the whole Thunderbird open?
Why? Isn't there a smaller background daemon just to check email and launch Thunderbird only when I click on the new mail notification?

Comment: unfortunately this is the only current way of doing this. You can otherwise install small apps like Unity mail which will perform the same function of checking email and providing notification. Then you can perform thunderbird when you have mail thereby saving memory.